# Print data from Delegate or some value is giving unexpected result

Tags: c#, delegates

I am trying to print some data using delegate, but It is not printing as I am expecting. whether It is due to delegate problem or any other issue. Any help would be appreciated.
my code is below.

```
class Program
{
    // declare delegate
    public delegate void Print(int value);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Print delegate points to PrintNumber
        Print printDel = PrintNumber;
        
        // or
        // Print printDel = new Print(PrintNumber);
            
        printDel(100000);
        printDel(200);

        // Print delegate points to PrintMoney
        printDel = PrintMoney;

        printDel(10000);
        printDel(200);
    }

    public static void PrintNumber(int num)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Number: {0,-12:N0}",num);
    }

    public static void PrintMoney(int money)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Money: {0:C}", money);
    }
}
```

I want to get below output

> Number: 100000.00
>
> Number: 200.00
>
> Money: 10000.00
>
> Money: 200.00

but current output is

> Number: 100000
>
> Number: 200
>
> Money: 10000
>
> Money: 200

Comment: What's the `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` when you run this code?

Comment: I did not learnt threading yet. but practicing C# in my company.

Comment: Thanks @germi It worked using currentculture. you rock.

Comment: To get the expected output just use the following formatters: number - {0,-12:N2}, money - {0:C2}. In this case "C2" and "N2" specifies that two digits should be always shown after the point.

Comment: you are also right @VitaliiIlchenko. I found it too. Thanks, you all helps alot.